# How to find all write references to a symbol in Roslyn?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I've been able to find all references, but they give me `ReferencedSymbol`s. Which is fine to find them in code, and with pain-staking analysis I should be able to identify writes like that (like follow multi-dot references, see if they're on the left side of an assignment, etc).

My question is, is it possible to ask Roslyn to determine if those references are read, write, read/write or unknown? Visual Studio's find references window does this, it assigns a reference type to each found reference, and since it's using Roslyn internally maybe this functionality is available somewhere? Even a heuristic is good enough.